# Keep the highest single match for each group

Tags: python, pandas, max, pandas-groupby

I'm struggling to use `pandas` to filter based on 2 `groupby` conditions

Let's say I have the below data:

- **each row** represents a comparisons of things (`id1`, `id2`) respectively from 2 data sources (`src1`,`src2`)
- **score** represents how similar the things are with each other (the higher the better)

```
data = [
    {'src1': 'A', 'id1': '111', 'src2': 'B', 'id2': '111', 'score': 10},
    {'src1': 'A', 'id1': '222', 'src2': 'B', 'id2': '222', 'score': 9},
    {'src1': 'A', 'id1': '111', 'src2': 'B', 'id2': '222', 'score': 2},
    {'src1': 'A', 'id1': '222', 'src2': 'B', 'id2': '111', 'score': 4},
    {'src1': 'A', 'id1': 'default', 'src2': 'B', 'id2': '111', 'score': 3},
    {'src1': 'A', 'id1': 'default', 'src2': 'B', 'id2': '222', 'score': 3},
]
```

What I'm trying to do is **groupby src1+id1+src2 and keep only rows with HIGHEST score AND count=1**

And here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['count'] = 1
groups = df.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score']).agg(
    {'id2': 'unique', 'count': 'sum'})
print(groups)
```

And I get the following:

```
                                id2  count
src1 id1     src2 score                   
A    111     B    2           [222]      1 # DISCARD because below has higher score (10>2)
                  10          [111]      1 # KEEP
     222     B    4           [111]      1 # DISCARD because below has higher score (9>4)
                  9           [222]      1 # KEEP
     default B    3      [111, 222]      2 # DISCARD because count=2
```

The problems I'm having:

- `WITHOUT reset_index()`: if I don't use `reset_index()`, whenever I try to access **score** or **count** for filtering I get a **KeyError**

```
groups = df.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score']).agg(
    {'id2': 'unique', 'count': 'sum'})
groups[groups['score'] == groups['score'].max()]

KeyError: 'score'
```

- `reset_index()`: if I use it, then I "lose" my groupby (ie each row becomes a new individual row and the result of my filtering only results 1 row

```
reset = groups.reset_index()
reset[reset['score'] == reset['score'].max()]

  src1  id1 src2  score  count    id2
1    A  111    B     10      1  [111]
```

**How can I extend below expression so for `EACH GROUP` I `ONLY KEEP` group rows with the `MAX score` and `count=1`?**

```
groups = df.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score']).agg(
    {'id2': 'unique', 'count': 'sum'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for get count without new helper column with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), then similar get `max` values by different grouping column, compare and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with chained conditions by `&` for `bitwise AND`:

```
m1 = df.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score'])['id1'].transform('size') <= 1
m2 = df.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2'])['score'].transform('max') == df['score']


df = df[m1 & m2]
print (df)
   id1  id2  score src1 src2
0  111  111     10    A    B
1  222  222      9    A    B
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df['count'] = 1
groups = df.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score']).agg(
    {'id2': 'unique', 'count': 'sum'})

m1 = groups['count'] <= 1
df = groups.reset_index(level=3)
m2 = (df.groupby(level=[0,1,2])['score'].transform('max') == df['score']).values

groups = groups[m1 & m2]
print (groups)
                       id2  count
src1 id1 src2 score              
A    111 B    10     [111]      1
     222 B    9      [222]      1
```

Comment: Since the 1st part of your solution is cleaner than the 2nd (adapted from my code), I'm wondering: **is it also as efficient?** It seems you're computing the `groupby` twice, and I'm doing this on a 500MB dataset so I'm concerned about performance

Comment: @PandaCoder - Hmm, hard question, the best test in real data. There are 2 groupby becuase different grouping columns.

Comment: **Isn't there a typo in 1st method?** shouldn't it be `['id2'].transform('size')` instead of `['id1'].transform('size')`? FYI tested on a 250MB dataset and **the 1st method seems considerably faster (0.9sec vs 2.6sec)**. Reasons might be that it doesn't compute the list of `id2` (`agg({'id2': 'unique'`), and doesn't add the `count` column (it only keeps relevant rows). **Other benefit of 1st method**: when i apply it to a dataframe that has other columns, the result is a dataframe that includes ALL columns, whereas with 2nd method I only get the groupby columns.

Comment: @PandaCoder - Actually it is same, need one column from DataFrame, not important what column is used. Reason is `transform` need one column, but `size` is counted from index, not by this column. This columns is only for compatibile with another functions.

Comment: But if use `transform` + `max`, here is max from column specify before `transform`

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways

```py
#your code
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['count'] = 1
groups = df.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score']).agg(
    {'id2': 'unique', 'count': 'sum'})

# Then do
groups = groups.sort_values(by=['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score'], ascending=False)
groups = groups.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2',]).head(1)[groups['count']==1]

                      id2  count
src1 id1 src2 score              
A    222 B    9      [222]      1
     111 B    10     [111]      1
```

Comment: It does work but throws a `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.` warning on your last groupby (Python=3.5.2, Pandas=0.23.0)

Comment: if it worries you then
`groups = groups.sort_values(by=['src1', 'id1', 'src2', 'score'], ascending=False)
groups = groups.groupby(['src1', 'id1', 'src2',]).head(1)
groups = groups[groups['count']==1]`